# Truncation of infinity-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

If we have a category $\mathcal{C}$, then we can see it as an $\infty$-category. Furthermore, we can truncate and $\infty$-category $\mathcal{X}$ to get a category $\mathcal{X}_{\leq 1}$. My question is if these functors are adjoint, i.e. if we have
$$\text{Hom}_{\mathfrak{Cat}}(\mathcal{X}_{\leq 1}, \mathcal{Y})\cong \text{Hom}_{\infty\text{-}\mathfrak{Cat}}(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$$
where $\mathcal{Y}$ is a category (which on the right is seen as an $\infty$-category).

Comment: I think you need to edit a bit your question. What is Y?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a bit of notation to be careful about here:

$\mathcal{X}_{\leqslant 1}$ is often used to denote the full subcategory of $\mathcal{X}$ of set-truncated object. For example if $\mathcal{X}$ is an $\infty$-topos, then $\mathcal{X}_{\leqslant 1}$ is its $1$-topos reflection.

with this definition, $\mathcal{X}_{\leqslant 1}$ is a $1$-category, but it is not the one that will have the property you want (it will be a right adjoint instead of a left adjoint, and only when restricted to finite limit preserving functor).

The $1$-category you want to consider is the homotopy category $h \mathcal{X}$ of $\mathcal{X}$, sometimes also denoted $\tau \mathcal{X}$, which is the category with the same objects as $\mathcal{X}$, and with the morphism sets

$$ h\mathcal{X}(a,b) \simeq \pi_0 ( \mathcal{X}(a,b) ) $$

Which does satisfies the property you ask.

A rigorous proof of this of course depends on what model of $\infty$-category you use, but if you use quasi-categories, this follows from points 1.2 and 1.8 in [Joyal notes](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/IMA/Joyal.pdf) on quasi-categories.

Comment: Just to clarify: the functor $(-)_{\leq 1}$ which restricts the fundamental $\infty$-groupoid to the fundamental groupoid of a space has no right adjoint? I'm asking because I would like to use this to give a simple proof of Seifert-van Kampen: For an open cover $U,V$ of $X$, we have a pushout $U\cap V\rightarrow U\times V\rightarrow X$. If we use the homotopy hypothesis, we get a pushout $\Pi(U\cap V)\rightarrow \Pi(U)\times \Pi(V)\rightarrow \Pi(X)$. If the truncation functor $\tau_{\leq 1}(-)$ were adjoint, then the pushout would be preserved, yielding a nice proof of S-vK.

Comment: The $\pi_1$ functor taking an $\infty$-groupoid to its fundamental groupoid is a left adjoint functor and this makes the groupoid version of S-vK. somehow trivial. (or at least it hides all the difficulty under the rug)

Comment: @curious: you do not get Seifert-van Kampen this way. What you get is that the fundamental groupoid functor preserves *homotopy* pushouts, but Seifert-van Kampen is a genuinely point-set result telling you when a point-set pushout is "close enough" to a homotopy pushout that the fundamental groupoid is what it should be.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm sorry, what is wrong with my argument? Or rather why does it prove a property of homotopy pushouts instead of pushouts?

Comment: @curious: you're working with $\infty$-categories and adjunctions between them and in $\infty$-category land you only have $\infty$-limits and colimits and those are what right adjoints resp. left adjoints preserve.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ah yes, thank you!